# Update Firebase displayName and profile photo URL using Google Account

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get some clearance in firebase but can't understand some things, I didn't find them in the documentation.

I found out how to update the `displayName` and the `photoURL` of a user (working in Android and Web now), but don't know how to get the data from the google account. Since I created the user through the console with a single email and password, there is no `displayName` and `photoURL` for this user. After that I logged with that mail (provider login with the example of friendlyChat given from Firebase) and the data didn't updated. What do I have to do to get this done?

Comment: You are creating an email/password user? If so, what do you mean, you don't know how to get the data from the google account?

Comment: I create the user through the console so there is only an email and a password given. After that, like in the friendlyChat, I used a login provider, Google, and the displayName and photoURL doesn't update automatically. They still be null in that case and I want to get the name and picture from Google now updatong thedata.

Comment: So you are signing using a Google account with the same email as the account you created in the console?

Comment: yes, that's exactly the case. I didn't though I described it that awful. Sorry ^^'

Comment: Did you enable the setting "multiple accounts per email" in the Firebase Console for your project?

Comment: Well, that was the only issue. The previous account got the symbol at the authentication tab from google (no more that grey mail), so I though it was already linked, but it wasn't really linked together, or at least correctly linked. The problem solved in a different way as I though.
Thank you a lot. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the [comment from bojeil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010380/update-firebase-displayname-and-profile-photo-url-using-google-account?noredirect=1#comment71286234_42010380) the only problem was the "multiple accounts per user" setting at the Firebase console in the project. It was disabled and the account were overwritten, because of the same email.